# GUI in Ada programming language

Tags: ada, gnat

How to make/create a GUI (Graphical User Interface) in Ada programming language? It is possible?

In Python, you can use tkinter to make a window form.

Comment: See also the approach illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38302974/230513).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know of 5 GUI frameworks for Ada (see the [Awesome Ada List](https://github.com/ohenley/awesome-ada?tab=readme-ov-file#graphical-user-interface) for some of them)

1. [GtkAda](https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada)
2. [Gnavi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnavi/)
3. [Claw](http://www.rrsoftware.com/html/prodinf/claw/claw.htm)
4. [Gnoga](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnoga/)
5. [QtAda](https://r3fowwcolhrzycn2yzlzzw-on.drv.tw/AdaStudio/)

[GtkAda](https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada) you can get for free from AdaCore.  [Claw](http://www.rrsoftware.com/html/prodinf/claw/claw.htm) can be purchased.  I'm not familiar with [Gnavi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnavi/) so I cannot comment on it much.  I've spent more time working with [Gnoga](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnoga/) and like both it and [GtkAda](https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada).  [GtkAda](https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada) is a native framework, but I like [Gnoga](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnoga/) because you can provide the GUI via webbrowser (so more easily cross platform) or you can integrate it with a native platform (including [GtkAda](https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada), Electron, etc.).  I'm not familiar much with [QtAda](https://r3fowwcolhrzycn2yzlzzw-on.drv.tw/AdaStudio/)

Also note, that if you can find another C or C++ GUI library, you can write bindings for it in Ada (it has a very good external language interface).

Comment: In addition I would like to mention Ada bindings to Qt:
https://r3fowwcolhrzycn2yzlzzw-on.drv.tw/AdaStudio/

Answer (score 4):

You could try [Tcl Ada Shell](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcladashell/), which supports Tk so should, I expect, be close-ish to `tkinter`. Personally I find it easiest to develop the user interface in Tcl/Tk and build the model in Ada.

Or there’s GtkAda - can be obtained from [AdaCore](https://www.adacore.com/download/more) for Linux, Windows (I assume you’re running the 2018 Community Edition?)

Answer (score 0):

I would add my support for [Gnoga](http://www.gnoga.com). I like it because

- It is not a binding; it is a GUI written in Ada.
- It is completely portable, because it uses a browser to provide the GUI